# Flip screen in Windows IoT

Tags: hardware, windows-iot

I'm writing an UWP application for a Raspberry Pi. The Pi is build in the official 7" touch screen case.

I was wondering if there is a possibility to flip the screen 180 degrees, when the user holds the Pi upside down. I'm also not sure if there is a gravity sensor in the Pi to detect the orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Raspberry Pi does not have an orientation sensor built in.

You can simply use of of the GPIOs along with a tilt sensor to detect the flip / Orientation.

Here is are example of tilt switches.

[image: ball tilt switch]
[image: mercury tilt switch]

Here is a project regarding [connecting a tilt switch to raspberry pi](http://osoyoo.com/2016/04/08/get-input-signal-from-raspberry-pi-gpio/). It includes a YouTube video demonstrating how to interface with tilt switch.